# Ruby replace string with a different string

Tags: ruby, gsub

I have the following string:

`"test,Hello, Inc.,test2"`

I want this to read:

`"test,Hello Inc.,test2"`

Essentially I want to convert all "`Hello, Inc.`" to "`Hello Inc.`". All commas should be removed from that string only.

I am using ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0.0. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work for you specific example.

```
"test,Hello, Inc.,test2".gsub(/Hello, Inc\./,"Hello Inc.")
```

Comment: You can use a string pattern, i.e. `"Hello, Inc."`

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string, x = "test,Hello, Inc.,test2", 'Hello, Inc'

my_string[x] = x.delete(',')

p my_string #=> "test,Hello Inc.,test2"
```